# In an Express controller, use a function that the current controller exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'd like to do this in my `main-controller.js` file:

```
var mainController = require( './main-controller' )

exports.add = function ( a, b ) {

    return a + b

}

exports.showAdded ( req, res ) {

    return res.json( mainController.add( req.query.a, req.query.b ) )

}
```

But requiring and referencing the current controller seems weird. Is there a way to do something like this instead?

```
this.add( req.query.a, req.query.b )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not `var` it:

```
var add = function (a, b) { };

exports.add = add;
```